# Multiple fields cascade mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cascade

I have a problem:

I have a table "likes" which is structured as this:

```
 -- likeID
 -- elementID
 -- elementType
```

The rest of the table is not important.
Let me explain the table: likeID is just the ID of the inserted like. elementID is the ID of the element being liked. elementID is not unique, because elements can have different elementTypes and therefore ther is the field elementType.

So let's say this:

I like element 1 of elementType 0. It would be `(likeID, elementID, elementType) VALUES (1,1,0)` now as a mysql insert.
Now I like element 1 of elementType 1. Now it would be`(likeID, elementID, elementType) VALUES (1,1,1)`

Now I have two extra tables:
The table for elementType 0 and the table for elementType 1.
They are structured similarly like this:

```
 -- thisElementID
 -- blabla other fields not important
```

and

```
 -- otherElementID
 -- blabla other fields not important
```

What I want now is a `ON DELETE CASCADE`. When I delete element 1 of elementType 0 which is part of the thisElementID-table, it should also delete the like for it. But the problem is, that element 1 of elementType 1 has the same ID value (otherElementID).

How can I manage this to work?
I hope you understand what I mean! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create triggers for each extra table:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER extra0_del AFTER DELETE ON extra0
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM likes WHERE elementID = OLD.thisElementID AND elementType = 0;
END;
//

CREATE TRIGGER extra1_del AFTER DELETE ON extra1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM likes WHERE elementID = OLD.otherElementID AND elementType = 1;
END;
//

delimiter ;
```

Replace `extra0` and `extra1` with names of your extra tables.